create a setting that prohibits importing certificates for users(without admin roots)
I want that using group policy we can configure the prohibition of importing certificates for the user, using the administrator or group policy we can import them.
Configuration is carried out in the computer infrastructure
I don’t quite understand how this can be done, maybe there is some information or sources where I can look.
